# QGIS: Symbology: Create Tercil for all values > 0 and tercil for all values< 0

Tags: qgis

I have a layer with multiple polygons each with a number of the commuter balance. You can see the histogram below (1st pic). I now want to symbolize this data.

I want a tercile calculation for all values < 0 and have 3 different red colors for it and a separate tercil calculation for all values > 0 and have 3 differenz green colors for it.

With the given algorithms it always includes 0 somewhere in the middle of the class breaks.

So preferably something like in the second image (the breaks here are just done by hand)

Is there any possibility beside split the layer apart and do two separate calculations?
[image: s]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you set your layer styling to Graduated, your Mode to Equal Interval, check the Symmetric Classification button setting it Around Zero with a Red,White,Green color ramp (not ideal for those with color blindness) I think you can achieve what you want.
[image: style settings]

Comment: Thanks, that's a first step. Unluckily it then only has the equal interval breaks. If you look to the histogram, a tercile would be better. Any possibility to use this option which tercils?

Comment: Right - that won't work for you then. It only seems to be available for equal interval. You should be able to use rule based styling with 6 classes. For example if a Tercile is the negative or positive range divided by 3 this could be the rule for the 2nd negative tercile. ("values_field"<(minimum("values_field")/3))and ("values_field">=(minimum("values_field")/3*2)) . If it is the sum of all the values in a negative range then it would be a more complicated formula but I assume still possible.